# Quicksort with swapping middle and first element in each partition

Tags: quicksort

Assume we have a standard, two-way partition QuickSort algorithm that always pivots on the first element. However, in this slight variant of QuickSort, we first swap the first and middle elements, and then pivot on the 'new' first element. My question is, will this change the worst-case running time?

My initial thinking was no, as in each sub-array the elements are still in random order relative to each other, and thus switching the first and middle elements would not change the overall runtime. But as I am interested in finding the worst-case scenario, I'm not sure if there's some 'special' array that would cause this slight variant to change the worst-case runtime of the original algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quicksort’s worst case is when the pivot is always the minimum or maximum. With that in mind, you can build a worst-case array:

- [1, 2] (every element in a two-element array is a min or max)
- [3, 1, 2] post-swap produces the above
- [1, 3, 2] pre-swap
- [4, 1, 3, 2] post-swap produces the above
- [1, 4, 3, 2] pre-swap
- [5, 1, 4, 3, 2] post-swap produces the above
- [4, 1, 5, 3, 2] pre-swap
- [6, 4, 1, 5, 3, 2] post-swap produces the above
- [1, 4, 6, 5, 3, 2] pre-swap
- etc.